# Method doesnt exit after return statement

Tags: java

I have a method that I have written to solve a maze recursively.

The method prints the correct output using `printMaze()` but it returns an incorrect value. I tried running the debugger and for some reason, the method keeps running even after entering the end condition: `if (x == g_x && y == g_y)` (the goal has been found so print visited and return it). After entering the end condition it prints but does not stop.

```
private static int[][] solver(int x, int y, int s_x, int s_y, int g_y, int g_x, int[][] maze, int[][] visited) {
        if (x == g_x && y == g_y) {
            solved = true;
            visited = printMaze(visited, g_x, g_y, s_x, s_y);
            return visited;
        }
        visited[x][y] = 1;
        if (isValid(x+1, y, maze) && isSafe(maze, visited, x+1, y)) {
            solution = solver (x+1, y, s_x, s_y, g_x, g_y, maze, visited);
        }
        if (isValid(x, y+1, maze) && isSafe(maze, visited, x, y+1)) {
            solution = solver (x, y+1, s_x, s_y, g_x, g_y, maze, visited);
        }
        if (isValid(x-1, y, maze) && isSafe(maze, visited, x-1, y)) {
            solution = solver (x-1, y, s_x, s_y, g_x, g_y, maze, visited);
        }
        if (isValid(x, y-1, maze) && isSafe(maze, visited, x, y-1)) {
            solution = solver (x, y-1, s_x, s_y, g_x, g_y, maze, visited);
        }
        visited[x][y] = 0;
        if (!solved) {
            return null;
        } else {
            return visited;
        }

    }
```

Helper methods:

```
private static int[][] printMaze(int[][] solution, int g_x, int g_y, int s_x, int s_y) {
        solution[g_x][g_y] = 1;
        solution[s_x][s_y] = 1;
        for (int i = 0; i < solution.length; i++) {
            for (int j = 0; j < solution[0].length; j++) {
                    System.out.print(" " + solution[i][j]); 
            }
            System.out.println();
        }
        System.out.println("////");
        return solution;
    }

    private static boolean isSafe (int[][] maze, int[][] visited, int x, int y) {
        return !(maze[x][y] == 1 || visited[x][y] == 1);
    }

    private static boolean isValid (int x, int y, int[][] maze) {
        return (x >= 0 && x < maze.length && y >= 0 && y < maze[0].length);
    }
```

Test grid with start = (0,0) and end = (0,2)

```
{0, 0, 0, 0},
{1, 1, 0, 0},
{0, 0, 0, 1},
{0, 0, 1, 0}
```

Solution printed (correct)

```
{1, 1, 1, 0},
{0, 0, 1, 0},
{1, 1, 1, 0},
{1, 1, 0, 0}
```

Solution returned (incorrect)

```
1 0 1 0
0 0 0 0
1 0 0 0
0 0 0 0
```

Comment: Have you analyzed the call stack? The method is recursive, thus the recursion has to unwind when a terminal state has been reached.

Comment: I did, I do not understand it entirely (due to a lot of calls to different java libraries) but I do not see why the recursion keeps going on after it reaches the end if statement (the one with the return statement).

Comment: Because the return probably returns to the calling side, which was most probably a recursive call.

Comment: I do not see the problem there either. My main method calls solver once, prints whatever it returns (the incorrect array) and that is it.

Comment: Because you are not checking the return value of the recursive call and you're continuing to check additional sides of the current position even if the previous side already provided a solution. When you to `solution = solver (x+1, y, s_x, s_y, g_x, g_y, maze, visited);`, you need to check `if (solution != null) return solution;`

Answer (score 0):

1. While it is possible to use an array with [x][y], it is much more common to use [cols][rows] which is [y][x].
2. Your method parameters are the wrong way around `, int g_y, int g_x,`.
3. The output of `printMaze` is so different from the returned array because in this example none of the recursion calls has returned yet. You're printing the array but after that all the recursions return, continue (and create a few more recursions) then call `visited[x][y] = 0;` before returning again. This almost completely wipes your `visited` array.

Comment: Oh! That makes sense, how do I fix the recursion part?